# Query to return multiple MAX values with HAVING clause

Tags: postgresql, max, having

I want to write a query that will return the name of students who did the most projects with the count of the project. I want the query to return a table like this:

| student_name | max_project_count |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | 2 |
| Anna Do | 2 |

This is the code I have so far but it's only giving me the 2 column names student_name and count, but not the result.

```
SELECT s.student_name, COUNT(student_name)
FROM student s
GROUP BY student_name 
HAVING COUNT(student_name) = (
   SELECT MAX(count)
   FROM (SELECT s.student_name, COUNT(*) AS count 
         FROM  student_project k, student s
         WHERE s.student_id = k.student_id
         GROUP BY student_name) AS foo)
```

Result I have right now:

| student_name | max_project_count |
| --- | --- |

These are the tables I have in my database:

student

| student_id | student_name |
| --- | --- |
| jd123 | John Doe |
| ad456 | Anna Do |
| js678 | Jess Smith |
| dk789 | Daniel Kim |

school_project

| project_id | project_name |
| --- | --- |
| math_1023 | Math Comp. |
| sci_9872 | Science Comp. |

student_project

| student_id | project_id |
| --- | --- |
| jd123 | math_1023 |
| ad456 | math_1023 |
| jd123 | sci_9872 |
| ad456 | sci_9872 |
| js678 | sci_9872 |
| dk789 | sci_9872 |

Answer (score 0):

```
with projects as (
   Select student_id, count(*) as pcount from student_project group by 1),
max_proj as (
   Select max(pcount) as max_project_count from projects)
Select 
  student_name, max_project_count
from student s,projects p,max_proj m
where 
     s.student_id=p.student_id and pcount=max_project_count
```